# create string from all checked values jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok so I do this:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" value="2" />
```

Then in javascript/jquery I'm trying to do something like this:

```
$('#btnHtml').click(function(){
for( var checks=''; $('.checkBoxClass:checked').val() ){
    var checks = checks+', ';
}
});
```

Let's say all of those checkboxes are checked, how can I get `var checks` to be a string of `'0, 1, 2'` ?

Still trying to get used to the for() in JS, it might be the completely wrong way of going about it. Not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Functional programming:

```
var str = $('.checkBoxClass:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get().join();
```

**Reference**: [`.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/), [`.get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/), [`.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Comment: Augh... *41 seconds*... +1 =)

Comment: Ah, `map()` my second favourite jQuery function after `filter()` :D

Comment: AWESOME! Exactly what I was aiming for! It won't let me accept the answer for another 7 minutes. Thanks so much!

Comment: @FelixKling yeah, but the OP had `, `

Comment: @Alnitak: Oh... I missed that. But I guess he will figure it out ;)

Comment: @FelixKling, you have saved lot of my time +1 is obvious.